# Consulta 3 tablas entre fechas con inner join

Tags: sql, vb.net

Consulto a 3 tablas con rango de fechas, mi pequeña aplicación esta en desarrollo, en la tabla principal o la primera tengo 4 registros en la segunda tengo 5 y en la tercera 7 registros, pero resulta que solo me extrae de las tablas 4 registros de cada tabla, cuando en la instrucción en el rango de la fecha le pongo como fecha final mas reciente al registro que esta en mi tabla esta es mi consulta

```
 Dim InfoIni As String = Format(DTPIni.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy")
 Dim InfoFin As String = Format(DTPFin.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy")
 Dim Totales As String = _
                "SELECT SUM (CUOTAS.CUOTA)AS CUOTA, SUM(CUOTAS.INASISTENCIA)AS INASISTENCIA, SUM(CUOTAS.MULTAS)AS MULTAS, SUM (CUOTAS.OTROS)AS NuevoSocio, " _
 & "SUM (PRESTAMOS.ABONO)AS ABONO, SUM (PRESTAMOS.CONDONO)AS CONDONO, SUM(PRESTAMOS.NUEVO)AS NuevoPrestamo, " _
    & "SUM(GASTOS.IMPORTE)AS ImporteGasto " _
    & "FROM (CUOTAS INNER JOIN PRESTAMOS ON PRESTAMOS.Id = CUOTAS.Id) " _
    & "INNER JOIN GASTOS ON GASTOS.Id = CUOTAS.Id WHERE CUOTAS.FECHA BETWEEN #" & InfoIni & "# AND #" & InfoFin & "#"
```

Cada tabla tiene un campo `Id`, uno de `Fecha`

**¿Cómo hago para rescatar todos los registros que estén en el rango?**

*Mis tablas estan en Access y VB.NET.*

Comment: no sera que solo te trae 4 registros de los 16 registros que tienen, solo esos cuatro cumplen la condicion de estas entre esas fechas ?

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! deberias mostrarnos los datos de la tabla y tambien que le pasas como parametro a la query para que podamos ver donde esta el error

Comment: Podrías poner tu diagrama?? y de ser posible que te expliques mejor

Answer (score 0):

Puede que los ID sean diferentes en los INNER JOIN, recuerda que en el INNER JOIN si no se cumple alguna condición no te devolverá el registro. Puedes usar un LEFT JOIN en su lugar y tal vez te funcione. Pero sin ver la data no puedo ayudarte mucho.